# Node 6: node-gyp rebuild for hiredis fails on macOS

Tags: node.js, macos-mojave

When running `yarn install` for a Node 6.11.1 project on macOS (Mojave) the `node-gyp rebuild` for `hiredis` fails:

XCode commandline tools have been installed via `sudo xcode-select --install`.

Node is installed via `nvm`.

```
error /Users/alexzeitler/src/some-project/node_modules/hiredis: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/alexzeitler/src/some-project/node_modules/hiredis
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.4.0
gyp info using node@6.11.1 | darwin | x64
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [ '/Users/alexzeitler/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/alexzeitler/src/some-project/node_modules/hiredis/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/alexzeitler/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/alexzeitler/.node-gyp/6.11.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/alexzeitler/.node-gyp/6.11.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/alexzeitler/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/alexzeitler/src/some-project/node_modules/hiredis',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/hiredis-c/deps/hiredis/sds.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/hiredis-c/deps/hiredis/read.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/hiredis-c.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/hiredis/src/hiredis.o
warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
In file included from ../src/hiredis.cc:1:
In file included from ../src/reader.h:1:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:51:
In file included from /Users/alexzeitler/.node-gyp/6.11.1/include/node/node.h:42:
/Users/alexzeitler/.node-gyp/6.11.1/include/node/v8.h:21:10: fatal error: 'utility' file not found
#include <utility>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/hiredis/src/hiredis.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/alexzeitler/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/alexzeitler/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/node" "/Users/alexzeitler/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/alexzeitler/src/some-project/node_modules/hiredis
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Update: using Node 8.11.1 via `nvm` everything works fine (but moving to 8.11.1 is not an option in this particular project yet).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

```
CXXFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.9" LDFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.9" yarn
```

Tried the answer from [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/469#issuecomment-51735454).

Comment: It works for me, thanks! Mac OS 10.14.1 (18B75), node version 6.11.3 (legacy project)

Answer (score 15):

If you are using XCode 10, you will notice that if you navigate to the `/usr`, you will not see a folder called `include` anymore, which is why the terminal complains of the absence of the header files which is contained inside the 'include' folder.

1. Go [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) then download and install: `Command Line Tools (macOS 10.14) for Xcode 10`
2. open `~/../../Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`
3. run `CXXFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.9" LDFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.9" yarn install`

Then you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, after installing the package, the `include` folder exists but the `node-gyp` error also remains.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler Are you compiling your own node C++ addon? Or is this happening after `npm install`?

Comment: It’s happening during npm install.

Comment: If I ignore the error, I can't install my npm packages. How do you deal with that?

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler The error happens after installing node modules. You should have node modules installed. Please also try `rm -rf node_modules && yarn cache clean --force && yarn install` and tell me if this helps. Maybe you need to remove existing node modules, clear yarn cache and install node modules. Also, do you have XCode 10 installed?

Comment: Tried it but didn't fix it. XCode 10 is installed.

Comment: Is the error really the same error as before? `node-gyp` and `npm` together print so much information when something fails that it's sometimes jolly hard to find the real reason for the failure. Please double-check that the error you are seeing is still `fatal error: 'utility' file not found`.

Comment: @Michal Would you mind validating my answer fixes it for you as well? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674032/90800

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler Looks awesome. :)

Comment: Its working for bower install too .
CXXFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.9" LDFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.9" bower install

Answer (score 0):

Faced this same issue once on Linux platform. Removing `node_modules` and `.node-gyp/` directory from home fixed the error.

Comment: Thanks, the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I stuck in this error for a long time and I paid the price... I ruined a laptop!

at the end this is the solution that worked for me:

the problem is not with `node-gyp` or `hiredis`.

there are 2 possibilities:

1- you're using incompatible `node` version

2- `python` symbolic link doesn't exist(my problem was this one)

the problem is with new version of python will remove a symbolic link and we should re-create the link:

install newest version of python:

```
brew install python
```

and after that create the symbolic link:

```
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/bin/python
```

of-course instead of `3.9` you should put your python version.